# resize button option box etc.ajax implement on internal pages

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

ive been studying this link but i cant figure out how he resize the option box and i want to know how to resize option box text box buttons etc. in jquery mobile but i cant find a way to resize them i also want to know if it is possible to impelement ajax on a jquery mobile that uses internal pages?and also how can you set the distance between label and textbox?here is the code of the link

http://jsfiddle.net/HwFFU/1/

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post" action="processForm.php">                    
        <li data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="children" class="select">Number of Kids</label>
            <select name="children" id="children" data-mini="true">
               <option value="0">0</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
            </select> 
        </li>
            <div id="kidsFields"></div>
    </form>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>

var html = '';
$('#children').on('change', function() {
    children = $(this).val();
    html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        html += '<label>Name</label><input type="text" id="textName' + i + '" name="child' + i + 'Name" /><label>Age</label><input type="text" name="child' + i + 'Age" id="textAge' + i + '" />';
    }

    $('#kidsFields').html(html);
    $('#kidsFields').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');

    $('.ui-page').trigger('create');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/HwFFU/20/  Here each Name/Age input field pair is on a single line with the inputs resized and the distance between label and input set.

When inserting the form elements, you can surround them with a div set to a data-role of fieldcontain (this also automatically stacks the elements on narrow screens):

```
   for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
      html += '<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label>Name</label><input type="text"   id="textName' + i + '" name="child' + i + 'Name" /><label>Age</label><input type="text" name="child' + i + 'Age" id="textAge' + i + '" /></div>';
   }
```

Then use CSS to set input field size and distance between label and input e.g.

```
#kidsFields .ui-input-text{
    width: 80px;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

And, yes you can use AJAX with jQM internal pages.  Perhaps you should create a separate and more specific question about that...

Comment: your answer is what i was looking for anyway do you know how to do the ajax thing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the AJAX?  You can make standard jQuery AJAX calls, parse the results and fill controls upon page navigations. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i wanted to load a certain div in a div.its the use of ajax that i know im using internal pages but all the examples im seeing now is using external pages so im not sure if it is even possible

Comment: I have updated the fiddle again (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/HwFFU/25/) adding a button at top left.  When you click it, it makes an ajax call and navigates to the second (internal) page.  When the AJAX call returns (artificial data and 2 second delay) it loads some text into a div on the second page.

Comment: very useful thank you.is there a way to load one page inside another i mean example i have this page 1 and page 2 when i click a button on page 1 page 2 will load inside page one all this in an internal page.so the url on top should not change right?same as on how you load an external page 2 into a page 1.the page doesnt change you just load the page 2 inside page 1